# See if phone number is stored in Firebase Firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want my aplication to show a mesasge that tells the user if his o her phone number exists in the database, but it always says that the phone number exist even when is not the case. What should I do to fix it?

```
bbdd.collection("Taxi").whereEqualTo("number", number).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if(task.isSuccessful) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Client exist in database. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Cliente does not exist in database.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

I expected to get a boolean value which would determine the message that would be shown to the user, but does it not what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having results does not make a query fail. A query can be successful even when there are no results.

If you want to check if there are results, check the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) you get back when the task succeeded:

```
if (task.isSuccessful && !task.result.isEmpty) { 
  ...
```

Comment: Ok, I changed the code and now it works. Thank you very much.